# Canny Edge algorithm vs OpenCv - Windows Phone 8

Tags: opencv, windows-phone-8

I'm making an app that gets the stream from the camera and uses the canny algorithm to display the edges. 
In android everything worked fine,using OpenCv to get the egdes and it was in real time. After that i went on developing to WP8, and found out WP8 doesn't support OpenCv yet. Because my only problem was that canny edge algorithm i got one from the internet,adapted the code to silverlight and it was a complete mess. It wasn't real-time at all,I was displaying the information in like 1 sec.I searched a bit about alternatives, found:EmguCv(but nothing about canny edge algorithm) and some guys that tried to compile an Opencv subset for W8 ARM.Even tried the second one,but ended up failing.My questions now are:

1. why on earth is it moving so slow?
2. if i manage to get a OpenCv library,will it be quicker?
3. do you guys have another alternatives/sugestions?

Comment: You can upload the camera image to the GPU and process it using a DirectX (edge-detector) shader.

Answer (score 0):

Think they're bringing our windows phone 8 support- with emgucv you can access all opencv functions and I'm sure canny edge is one of them. Apparently opencvsharp is good. As for speed- no idea.